# Suite bar link to open a email with current site link

Tags: email, suite-links

Is there any possibility to create a suite bar link to open an email with the current site url in the body area? At the moment we are using a solution to create suite bar links but it is only possible to insert a "url".

[image]

Maybe someone has an idea.
Thank you

Comment: Do you want to return the URL of the site dinamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achive this by createing a calculated field with the following formula :

```
="<a href='mailto:"&mail&"?subject=look at this website&body= "&siteURL&"'>"&mail&"</a>"
```

**Note:** set the data type as number to show the field as hyperlink

Where the `mail` is the email field in your list as text , and SiteURL is the field that will updated with the current site URL value via a workflow on item add.

To get site URL , try to create a workflow to update list item with the value of `[Workflow Context: Current Site URL]`

If you don't need to create a workflow, create a new column that will hold the site url manually and hide it from the default view and set it in calculated field.

**Alternative solution:**

you can also get the Site URL via javascript and set the value of URL field as the following :

Edit add page > add script editor > add the following code

```
<script>
function URLwithBody()
{
var mail = document.getElementById("mail_96381d5c-8554-4d7f-9b73-540469240fe9_$TextField").value
var body= "?subject=look at this website&body=" ;
host = window.location.href;
host = host.substring(0, host.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

var finalURL= mail +body + host;
document.getElementById("mailwithbody_8b3ec4fe-5586-4b72-8e32-2343e976a07e_$UrlFieldUrl").value = finalURL;

 }

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("URLwithBody");
</script>
```